# React Navigation - Handle two button to pass different param while navigating the same screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is it possible to handle next screen value depending on which button is pressed in `React Navigation`,

I've search any possible duplicate issue like I have, but spending couple hours not yet finding that.

Let say I have a code like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
        <Button
          title="Go to Details 2"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("Button pressed on Homescreen is " + Button)
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen With Button Go To Details Or Details 2</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    Details: {
      screen: DetailsScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}
```

My Goal is how the `Detail` screen knowing if button `Go To Details` or `Go To Details 2` is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send value to navigator Details page while navigating like

First Button click :

```
 <Button
     title="Go to Details"
     onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', { title: 'Details 1'})}/>
```

Second Button click :

```
 <Button
     title="Go to Details"
     onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', { title: 'Details 2'})}/>
```

And then on 'Details Screen':
Access that value : `{this.props.navigation.state.params.title}`

So final code will be like this:

```
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("Button pressed on Homescreen is " +{this.props.navigation.state.params.title})
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Button Pressed : {this.props.navigation.state.params.title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this will work.